# Is there any research for CoCo-Bond in a two factor model?

Tags: bond, pricing

Basically I am trying to price CoCo-Bond with the AT1P from Brigo. But in the end this isn´t a two factor model. Is there any concret research about this topic?

Kind regards,

WLS

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a paper with Alex Shubert. You can get it on archive.org.

Comment: can you please provide a link? It will be even more helpful if you can provide a short induction.

Comment: I haven't looked closely but this could be the one: https://archive.org/details/AnalyticPricingCoCoBonds.